# Option symbol conversion

Tags: options, r, programming

Maybe more of a programming question,
Is there a Ruby gem to facilitate conversion of an option symbol notation from one form to another?

For example, one source provides **TZA1220J18**

but an API for a brokerage strictly goes by **TZA^^^121020C00018000**

whose description is **TZA Oct12 18 Call**

If I figure out how to do this indirectly, by invoking R from with Ruby for example, which R library would I need that given the first form, can return one of the later two notations as strings?

I understand that exact days-of-month for option expiration may be irregular, so perhaps some website has an API to assist showing option symbols under different conventions?

Comment: How can I migrate question this to SE? Anyway a useful reference to decode the new option symbol I have found is http://moneymorning.com/2010/02/01/new-options-trading-symbols/. If I always assume 3rd Friday/Saturday of the month I can avoid online lookups.